# Cowardly PHP script just quits when error is encountered

Tags: php, curl

I have a cURL function that spiders all the webpages specified in an array. The array is called $to_be_spidered, I have the function being executed like so:

```
$to_be_spidered = array('http://google.com', 'http://mysterysite.com', 'http://yahoo.com');

for ($i = 0; $i != count($to_be_spidered); $i++) {

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0); // set cURL timeout
        $html= curl_exec($ch);

        // error handling
        if (!$html) {
                echo "<br />cURL error number:" .curl_errno($ch);
                echo "<br />cURL error:" . curl_error($ch);
                exit;
        }

// etc. etc...

    }
```

Now the problem is, if a webpage returns an error like a 404, the script is killed. For example if mysterysite.com is not found the script does not attempt to spider yahoo.com. It just quits that and all the links after.

I would like it to quit attempting to spider the error link and move on to the next link in the queque. I tried changing "exit" to "continue" but no luck. It still stops. Am I doing something wrong or is this specific to using cURL?

Comment: seem's you are the one inspiring the cowardliness, I believe it is `exit;` that makes it quit :P

Comment: @Trufa He's already indicated changing `exit` to `continue` without any change so that's not the underlying issue

Comment: @Phil WOW! was that there before??? My bad (specially) if it was!

Comment: @Trufa No edits (so far). Egg, meet face ;-)

Comment: @Phil I'm barking at the screen right now. :)

Answer (score 2):

You should change `exit` to `continue` as indicated.

Are you receiving any errors? Is error reporting enabled? A fatal error will halt execution.

Put this at the top of your script

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

---

Also, where are you using the URL from `$to_be_spidered`? Another thing (also related), your loop would look much nicer using `foreach`

```
foreach ($to_be_spidered as $target_url) {
```

Answer (score 2):

`exit()` terminates the current script... so, don't use it if that's not the behavior you're looking for.

```
if (!$html) {
    echo "<br />cURL error number:" .curl_errno($ch);
    echo "<br />cURL error:" . curl_error($ch);
} else {
    // etc. etc...
}
```

Comment: This isn't addressing the underlying problem as the OP has already indicated trying `continue` instead. My guess is it could be anything from the bad "for loop" conditions to never actually using `$to_be_spidered[$i]`

Answer (score 2):

The two previous suggestions will work.  However I noticed another potential bug in the code.

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php

> "if the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option
>   is set, it will return the result on
>   success, FALSE on failure."

So if **curl_exec** returns data that equals the empty string or zero (or anything else determined as FALSE in http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php), this script will incorrectly read it as an error.

So you'll need to make sure you check the type.  The following should work:

```
if( $html===FALSE ) {
    // Report error
} else {
    // deal with content
}
```

Also I recommend wrapping each CURL request in a try catch loop as well.

Comment: +1 Always good to check for expected values using the `===` operator. I don't think cURL throws exceptions though and doubt any successful result could be evaluated as `false`